# silverstripe 4 translatable module

Tags: silverstripe, silverstripe-4

I'm trying to understand how to setup a multilingual website with SilverStripe4. I can find this for SilverStripe3:
https://userhelp.silverstripe.org/en/3/optional_features/working_with_translations/about-translatable

But I can't find any documentation for the translatable module for SilverStripe 4.

**Is this not supported by SilverStripe 4 to build multilingual websites? Or is there some other way to make the website multilingual now?**

Comment: you can use silverstripe/silverstripe-translatable for silverstripe 4: https://github.com/silverstripe/silverstripe-translatable/tree/master

Comment: @jbe that's not true, the composer constraints say it can be installed but the module hasn't been updated for SilverStripe 4 and is unlikely to be. It's recommended to use tractorcow/silverstripe-fluent for SilverStripe 4 instead

Comment: @RobbieAverill Thanks, I did't know that. A notice in the readme would be nice then, because it looks like it was ready for Silverstripe 4.x.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Silverstripe CMS itself can already be translated by adding i18n files to lang in your mysite or module folder.

To implement a solid site translation for end users with language switch, proper linking and so on i would suggest using https://github.com/tractorcow/silverstripe-fluent as already stated by @RobbieAverill.